# Htaccess : my rewriting rules doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my .htacess file, my rewriting rules doesn't work. Here the rules :

```
RewriteRule ([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+).pdf$ $1/$2/document.pdf [NC,L]

RewriteRule ([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9-a-zA-Z_-]+).pdf$ $1/$2/$3/document.pdf [NC,L]
```

When I comment one of the rules, the uncommented rules works. But the two rules together doesn't work and apache log contains :

```
[Tue Oct 20 15:33:57 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://127.0.0.1/~guest/example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/
```

Any idea ? Thank you in advance, cordially.

Comment: did you try reversing the rule?

Comment: Thank you very much ! You solved my problem. By reversing the rules order, it works !